# Weird behavior in simulating LLN for standard deviations in R

Tags: r, standard-deviation, law-of-large-numbers

I am simulating the law of large numbers and how it applies to standard deviation, as well. I wrote this code that works well but there is something that I am having a hard time understanding.

```
n <- 1000

dice.sd <- numeric(n)

sd(1:6) #1.870829

for (i in 1:n) {

dice.sd[i] <- sd(sample(1:6, i, replace = TRUE))

}

plot(dice.sd)

abline(h=1.870829)

abline(h=1.7078)
```

As you can see, I made this loop to simulate LLN for standard deviations. According to the documentation, the sd() function uses n-1 for calculating the sample standard deviation, which should be about 1.87 for a die. However, when I run my simulation and graph the results, the standard deviation is converging to about 1.7078, which is the population standard deviation (using just n). Why is this the case? My loop originally was using the sample standard deviation, so why is it converging to the population standard deviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling a fair six-sided die (or conducting equivalent simulations in `R`) gives you a [discrete uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)  random variable $X \sim \text{U} \{ 1,...,6 \}$, which has true standard deviation:

$$\mathbb{S}(X) = \sqrt{\frac{(6-1+1)^2-1}{12}} = \sqrt{\frac{35}{12}} = 1.707825.$$

That is the true standard deviation of the underlying distribution, so the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) says that the sample standard deviation should converge to this value (in various probabilistic senses) as $n \rightarrow \infty$.  In the code below I repeat your simulation analysis and show that this is occurring.  (For replicable examples you should [set the seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605271/) when you do simulations, and you should also show us your graph.)

```
#Simulate the sample standard deviations
m <- 6
n <- 1000
set.seed(7412040876)
DICE.SD <- numeric(n)
for (i in 1:n) { 
  SAMPLE <- sample.int(m, size = i, replace = TRUE)
  DICE.SD[i] <- sd(SAMPLE) }

#Plot the simulations and true standard deviation
SD <- sqrt((m^2-1)/12)
plot(DICE.SD, ylim = c(0, 3),
     main = 'Simulated Sample Standard Deviations for a Fair Die', 
     xlab = 'n', ylab = 'Sample Standard Deviation')
abline(h = SD, lty = 2, lwd = 2, col = 'red')
```

[image]